# What technique did Minato use to separate the Kyuubi into two parts?

Tags: naruto

When the Kyuubi attacked the Leaf Village after being hypnotized by Tobi, Minato as a last resort separated the Kyuubi into two parts. Recently in the latest chapters of the manga, it looks like the Kyuubi was separated into Black and White, as in Evil and Good, or Yin and Yang.

What technique did he use? Did he really split the Kyuubi into good and evil halves? Or is it just something made up for the split?

Comment: Dead Demon Consuming Seal ???

Comment: i dont know ._.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minato used the Death Reaper Seal to seal the Yin half the Kyuubi in him, then he used the Eight Trigram Seal combined with the 4 Element Seal to seal the Yang Half of the Kyuubi in Naruto.

From [Naruto Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kurama)

> During its attack on Konoha, Minato Namikaze sacrificed his life by
>   splitting the fox's chakra into two: sealing the Yang half within his
>   son and sealing the Yin half within himself.

---

Lower down in the page:

> Since Kurama's chakra was too immense to be sealed within an infant
>   like Naruto, Minato first used the Dead Demon Consuming Seal to
>   separate and seal its Yin half within himself and then prepared the
>   Eight Trigrams Seal to imprison the Yang half within Naruto

The 4 Element Seal was used so that the chakra of the Nine Tailed Fox would slowly leak out from the Eight Trigrams Seal and merge with Naruto's own chakra.

Comment: In addition, the "Four Symbol Seal" is actually the "Four Element Seal" said by Naruto when asked by Killer Bee during his training.

Comment: @NaraShikamaru Yes, there may be a difference in terminology due to different English Transalations available over the internet. :)

Comment: Follow up question: How such technique separate the good from the bad?

Comment: @NaraShikamaru as seen during the battle between Orochimaru and Sarutobi, the Third was able to seal only a part of Orochimaru, namely Orochimaru's hand. So I guess, Minato too did something similar and sealed only a part of the nine tails in him.

Comment: But the "Orochimaru's hand" doesn't mean that it is a "bad hand" or a "good hand" right? I think you misunderstood. My point is you can't just separate the "creamer" and the "coffee" if they mixed up in hot water.

Comment: Yin or yang don't mean good or bad. They mean mind and body. Minato sealed the yang in Naruto because the yin would have more mind power, and would be harder to control.

Comment: *"Black and White as Evil and Good like a Yin-Yang"*, not yin and yang.